# Calculate mean over values in lines of CSV file if month, week day, and time match a conditon

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a CSV file in this format:

`date,      month,  weekday,    hour,   data
1/1/2016,  January, Friday,     0,   0.003333`

It has 1000s of lines and months range from jan to may, there are 7 week days and 24 values for hours.

Now I want to calculate mean over data values from a specific set where let's say month = January and weekday=Friday and hour=0. I could write specific 'if' conditions for each case but there are 100s of combinations and would take me forever to write. Instead, I thought of storing these values in lists and then iterating over the lists in the following manner:

```
f_obj1.readline()
    temp_list = []
    list_of_days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
    list_of_months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May']
    list_of_hours = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23']


    for line in f_obj1:
        list_of_values_in_a_line = line.strip().split(',')
            for month in list_of_months:
                for day in list_of_days:
                    for hour in list_of_hours:
                          list_of_values_in_a_line = line.strip().split(',')
                          if list_of_values_in_a_line[1] == month and list_of_values_in_a_line[2] == day and list_of_values_in_a_line[3] == hour:
                                 print (month + "   " + day + "   "+ hour+ "   " + list_of_values_in_a_line[8])
                          if list_of_values_in_a_line[8] != '':                        
                            value = float (list_of_values_in_a_line[8])
                            temp_list.append(value)
                        print (temp_list)
                        temp_list = [float(i) for i in temp_list]
                        print (temp_list)
                        print (threshold)
        temp_list = []
```

Basically, I'm trying to go store the values for specific combinations of month, weekday and hour in temp_list and then calculate average over the temp_list and then display it on the screen. Then move on to do the same for the next combination. I had to do some type conversions along the way as you may notice.

However, I'm not creating the combinations right because the program either gets stuck in loops or gives me wrong values.

Comment: At a first glance this line "temp_list = [float(i) for i in temp_list]" looks incorrect... Are you trying to append the new value to the list? Then the syntax should be temp_list.append(float(i))

Comment: You need [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org). It provides everything you need including csv reading and data filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider creating a list of all possible combinations, then use it in iteration for row averaging.

**Data** N=20 *(for illustration, notice first and last two repeat (month/day/hour combination)*

```
date        month       weekday     hour    data
1/1/2016    January     Friday      0       0.003333
11/1/2014   January     Friday      0       0.754317765
7/3/2012    July        Tuesday     10      0.527339392
8/4/2013    August      Sunday      21      0.201672642
11/15/2014  November    Saturday    4       0.180149373
1/28/2014   January     Tuesday     7       0.938470995
10/20/2013  October     Sunday      22      0.970212458
1/5/2014    January     Sunday      17      0.315196427
11/27/2012  November    Tuesday     6       0.252064108
4/11/2012   April       Wednesday   19      0.897632292
5/2/2014    May         Friday      7       0.135751904
4/14/2012   April       Saturday    16      0.809566157
5/14/2013   May         Tuesday     18      0.822701475
5/16/2012   May         Wednesday   15      0.436915248
3/19/2013   March       Tuesday     2       0.590245713
10/6/2012   October     Saturday    7       0.456019852
8/10/2012   August      Friday      16      0.243372334
5/30/2013   May         Thursday    0       0.067076705
4/7/2014    August      Thursday    7       0.358928591
8/2/2012    August      Thursday    7       0.463650973
```

**Script**

```
import csv

list_of_months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
                  'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
list_of_days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
list_of_hours = list(range(24))

# ALL POSSIBLE COMBINATIONS
combn = [[m, d, h] for m in list_of_months for d in list_of_days for h in list_of_hours]

# RETRIEVE CSV DATA
data = []
with open('CSVData.csv', 'rt') as csvfile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    next(csvReader)
    for row in csvReader:
        data.append(row)

# ITERATE OVER COMBINATIONS AND CSV DATA CONDITIONALLY APPENDING AVERAGES
avgs = []
for c in combn:
    cntval = 0; sumval = 0
    for d in data:
        if c[0] == d[1] and c[1] == d[2] and c[2] == int(d[3]):
            sumval = sumval + float(d[4])
            cntval += 1

    if cntval > 0:        
        avgs.append([c[0], c[1], c[2], sumval/cntval])

for a in avgs:
    print(a)
```

**Output** N=18 *(notice now original first and last two are now aggregated with average)*

```
# ['January', 'Tuesday', 7, 0.938470995]
# ['January', 'Friday', 0, 0.37882538250000003]
# ['January', 'Sunday', 17, 0.315196427]
# ['March', 'Tuesday', 2, 0.590245713]
# ['April', 'Wednesday', 19, 0.897632292]
# ['April', 'Saturday', 16, 0.809566157]
# ['May', 'Tuesday', 18, 0.822701475]
# ['May', 'Wednesday', 15, 0.436915248]
# ['May', 'Thursday', 0, 0.067076705]
# ['May', 'Friday', 7, 0.135751904]
# ['July', 'Tuesday', 10, 0.527339392]
# ['August', 'Thursday', 7, 0.411289782]
# ['August', 'Friday', 16, 0.243372334]
# ['August', 'Sunday', 21, 0.201672642]
# ['October', 'Saturday', 7, 0.456019852]
# ['October', 'Sunday', 22, 0.970212458]
# ['November', 'Tuesday', 6, 0.252064108]
# ['November', 'Saturday', 4, 0.180149373]
```

---

And with pandas, Python's data analysis package, `groupby()` can easily run the mean aggregation:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('CSVData.csv')
df = df.groupby(['month', 'weekday', 'hour'])['data'].agg(['mean'])

#                             mean
# month    weekday   hour          
# April    Saturday  16    0.809566
#          Wednesday 19    0.897632
# August   Friday    16    0.243372
#          Sunday    21    0.201673
#          Thursday  7     0.411290
# January  Friday    0     0.378825
#          Sunday    17    0.315196
#          Tuesday   7     0.938471
# July     Tuesday   10    0.527339
# March    Tuesday   2     0.590246
# May      Friday    7     0.135752
#          Thursday  0     0.067077
#          Tuesday   18    0.822701
#          Wednesday 15    0.436915
# November Saturday  4     0.180149
#          Tuesday   6     0.252064
# October  Saturday  7     0.456020
#          Sunday    22    0.970212
```

Comment: Thank you, both approaches do exactly what I intend. However, I'm getting an error in: `sumval = sumval + float(d[4])` which is: `ValueError: could not convert string to float:`. I checked my CSV and data is just values -- without any quotes around them. So those are just some float values. Why are they being treated as strings?

Comment: Also, there are missing values in the 'data field' for some combinations. In  that case, the type conversion would fail I guess?

Comment: Alright, so I think I fixed it by including a condition to check if 'data' field is 'null': `if c[0] == d[1] and c[1] == d[2] and c[2] == int(d[3]):
            if d[10]:            
                print(d[10])
                sumval = sumval + float(d[10])
                cntval += 1`

Comment: Indeed, missing values should be handled accordingly and won't convert properly. I'm glad you found a workaround and that I helped!